# How to jump long in DiRT 2

Tags: dirt-2

One of the online tournaments is Long Jump, I was wondering which tracks are good for jumping long distances, as any good ramps I find always reset the the car immediately back on the track.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [Codemasters Forum](http://community.codemasters.com/forum/dirt-2-game-consoles-1175/400468-longest-jump.html), it says: "Certain Mountains, I believe the ridges in some area's of Malaysia can launch you MILES allowing you to get ridiculously high and long jumps."

This video are in the Ladang Long - Malaysia

More youtube videos are made and can help you to find the track you want.

Edit: [Others](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/955086-dirt-2/51502569) say that in L.A. you'll find a good track for long jump.

I think you can find on a big amount of tracks a place to get a long or high jump.